# How to make REST on a model through the nested model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to make REST part which on **url** would look like this:

**GET POST api/groups/{group_id}/users/**

**PUT PATCH DELETE api/groups/{group_id}/users/{user_id}**

So I could see users which are related to the pointed group. Is there any way for such case? Thanks :)

Code example:

**.models**

```
class User(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have simplest **serializers** and **view sets** look like:

**.serializers**

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'

class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

**.views**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupSerializer
```

Comment: A "django way" would be something like `/api/users/{user_id}/` - using query parameters instead of nested path. Might seem a bit weird but if you have object id, there's no need to put parent id in url. For list action, `/groups/{group_id}/users/` would be `/users/?group_id={group_id}`

Comment: @nenadp this is actually an easy and right way but there is a task which asks something look like that I wrote. Not sure someone also has such problem but anyway I'd like to see the ways to solve this one.

Comment: I guess you could play with [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request), manually taking care of request kwargs and many other things django would normally do for you. If that's a specific task for university or something that's cool, but in general you should avoid such things

Comment: Can you please show your approach of `serializer classes` and `views`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers). It's a really nice library that helps define routes exactly like this.

A quick example is for URLs like this:

```
/domain/ <- Domains list
/domain/{pk}/ <- One domain, from {pk}
/domain/{domain_pk}/nameservers/ <- Nameservers of domain from {domain_pk}
/domain/{domain_pk}/nameservers/{pk} <- Specific nameserver from {pk}, of domain from {domain_pk}
```

The usage will be:

```py
# urls.py

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'domains', DomainViewSet)

domains_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'domains', lookup='domain')
domains_router.register(r'nameservers', NameserverViewSet, basename='domain-nameservers')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(domains_router.urls)),
)
```

```py
# views.py

class NameserverViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Nameserver.objects.filter(domain=self.kwargs['domain_pk'])
```